# How to save this string into XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this string variable:

```
string xml = @"<Contacts> 
    <Contact> 
    <Name>Patrick Hines</Name> 
    <Phone Type=""Home"">206-555-0144</Phone> 
    <Phone Type=""Work"">425-555-0145</Phone> 
    <Phone Type=""Mobile"">332-899-5678</Phone> 
    <Address> 
        <Street1>123 Main St</Street1> 
        <City>Mercer Island</City> 
        <State>WA</State> 
        <Postal>68042</Postal> 
    </Address> 
    </Contact> 
    <Contact> 
    <Name>Dorothy Lee</Name> 
    <Phone Type=""Home"">910-555-1212</Phone> 
    <Phone Type=""Work"">336-555-0123</Phone> 
    <Phone Type=""Mobile"">336-555-0005</Phone> 
    <Address> 
        <Street1>16 Friar Duck Ln</Street1> 
        <City>Greensboro</City> 
        <State>NC</State> 
        <Postal>27410</Postal> 
    </Address> 
    </Contact>
</Contacts>";
```

How can I save this string into an XML file in my drive c? Using c#.

Comment: Use System.IO.File class methods.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The fact that it's XML is basically irrelevant. You can save any text to a file very simply with [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllText("foo.xml", xml);
```

Note that you can also specify the encoding, which defaults to UTF-8. So for example, if you want to write a file in plain ASCII:

```
File.WriteAllText("foo.xml", xml, Encoding.ASCII);
```

Comment: what if sir if i want to read my saved xml back into my program as a string? Should I use `XmlTextReader`?

Comment: @yonan2236: Then just use `File.ReadAllText`. As Jon Skeet says, you don't really appear to be doing anything XML-specific; you only want to do basic file I/O on text data?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... I'm just trying something.

Comment: I guess you're right. Is my question wrong? Should I change it?

Comment: @yonan2236: It's not that the question is *wrong* as such - it's more that it's mixing two concepts: saving a text file, and the contents of the text file being XML.

Comment: I'd also recommend adding an XML declaration to the string, and ensuring the encoding in the declaration matches that in the WriteAllText method. It's likely to save a fair amount of hassle at later date, judging by the frequency of XML encoding questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: File.WriteAllText default to UTF-8? Really? Isn't Unicode the default in .NET?

Comment: @stt106: UTF-8 is the default for all I/O in .NET. Strings are represented as sequences of UTF-16 code units, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Not sure then why it still shows UTF-16 in my case when using the default encoding...

Comment: @stt106: You'd need to give far more details - what *exactly* are you doing, and what is "it" that's showing UTF-16? But `File.WriteAllText(string, string)` acts as it's documented to - it uses UTF-8.

Comment: I did `File.WriteAllText(string, string)` and in XML Spy it shows `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`

Comment: @stt106: Well that just means that your string contains the text `encoding="utf-16"`. That wouldn't be changed by any encoding specified in `File.WriteAllText` - it's just part of the string. The file will still be encoded in UTF-8, meaning that the XML declaration is effectively lying.

Comment: Any idea why `XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(somePath))` works locally but not on Teamcity? The file does have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` at the top but as mentioned above that should not affect .NET using `UTF-8` encoding for I/O. The fact that it works on my dev machine but not on Teamcity puzzles me.

Comment: @stt106: I'd check what the actual bytes are on both machines. If there's anything non-ASCII, that could easily cause problems, and could be quite subtle depending on how each file is represented. Ideally, try to take a hash (just MD5 would be fine) on both machines.

Comment: I am pretty sure the file is ASCII compatible as it's just a small file with English letters and numbers. Will try what you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(yourXMLString);
xdoc.Save("myfilename.xml");
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need to do any processing on the string  (with an XML library, for example), you could just do:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\myXml.xml", xml);
```

Comment: +1 For using correct path, should save some head-scratching for the OP. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("filename.xml", xml );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
string path = @"C:\testfolder\testfile.txt";

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path))
{    
    file.Write(text);  
}
```

You can also do this after you've created an XML Document, but it is slower:

```
xdoc.Save
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the string as-is without performing any check on whether it's well-formed or valid, then as has been answered above, use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\myfilename.xml", xml );`

As has also been noted, this defaults to saving the file as UTF-8, but you can specify encoding as Jon Skeet mentioned.

I'd recommend adding an XML declaration to the string, e.g.,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and ensuring the encoding in the declaration matches that in the WriteAllText method. It's likely to save a fair amount of hassle at later date, judging by the frequency of XML encoding questions on stackoverflow.

If you want to ensure the XML is well-formed and/or valid, then you will need to use an XML parser on it first, such as `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);` That method is also overridden if you want to preserve whitespace: `XDocument.Parse(str, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)`

You can then perform validation on it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340331.aspx

before saving to file: `doc.Save("C:\myfilename.xml");`