# how to edit utf-16 xml file if it have string line after the end of the main Node

Tags: c#, xml, declaration, utf-16, innertext

I have Special XML file with `utf-16` encoding type. this file used to store data and I need to Edit it Using C# windows forms Application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<cProgram    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="b0eb0c7e-f4de-4bc7-9e62-7a086a8c2fn8" Version="16.01" xmlns="cProgram">
  <Serie>N    </Serie>
  <No>123456</No>
  <type>101</type>
  <Dataset4>larg data here 2 million char</Dataset4>
</cProgram>123456FF896631N    4873821012013-06-14
```

the problem is: it is not ordinary XML file
Because at the very End of the file I have a string line too, and that would give this error

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line x, position x
```

when I try to load it as xml file

I tried to temporary replace the last line and get it back after I change the inner text, and it works But I lost the declaration Line and I didn't find a way to rewrite it when I have that text at the end of the file !_
so I need to change the `InnerText` of (Serie) and (No) nodes 
but I don't Want to lose the declaration Line or the string text at the end of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allow me to answer my question 
when I used doc.Load(filepath); it always give Error cause of the disturbing last Line 
and C# use UTF-8 as defaults to work with xml files.But in this question it is UTF-16
So I found a very short way to do this & replace innertext with string as I want

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
        text = text.Replace("<Serie>N", "<Serie>"+textBox1.Text);
        text = text.Replace("<Nom>487382","<Nom>"+textBox2.Text);
       //saving file with UTF-16
        File.WriteAllText("new.xml", text , Encoding.Unicode);
```

Question related to this [blog]: [How to save this string into XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721735/how-to-save-this-string-into-xml-file) "it is much more answer related than being Question related"

Answer (score 0):

try this piece of code:

```
string line = "";
string[] stringsperate = new string[] { "</cProgram>" };
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C://blah.xml"))
{
     line = sr.ReadToEnd();
     Console.WriteLine(line);
}
string text = line.Split(stringsperate, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
text += "</cProgram>";
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.LoadXml(text);
Console.Read();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: A.Khatri : it is not work .. maybe because it is large file (2milion character inside dataset4)
and it dose not say how to change the ineer text !

Comment: with the xml you have provided, it is working fine. you have to try editing inner text work as google is full of help.

Comment: maybe you miss understand me .. 
I know how to change inner text , But with this file I can't
and my question was how can I change it .
there is nothing on google about this, it is Special case cause of the last line !

Comment: is it in end of file or after `</cProgram>`?

Comment: both . it is the last line in the XML file,and after '</cProgram>' ,as I provided.

Comment: i think i am still not getting what you are trying. anyways Thanks for tolerating me, as i am out of ideas now

Answer (score 0):

`XDocument.Save()` should persist the XML declaration line if the declaration exists initially. I also checked with your XML and the declaration line saved as expected :

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
<cProgram    xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" ID=""b0eb0c7e-f4de-4bc7-9e62-7a086a8c2fn8"" Version=""16.01"" xmlns=""cProgram"">
  <Serie>N    </Serie>
  <No>123456</No>
  <type>101</type>
  <Dataset4>larg data here 2 million char</Dataset4>
</cProgram>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
doc.Save("test.xml");
```

So you can implement your idea to temporarily replacing the last line and get it back after changing the inner text.

Fyi, `XDocument`'s `.ToString()` method doesn't write XML declaration line, but `.Save()` method does. Question related to this : [How to print <?xml version="1.0"?> using XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957124/how-to-print-xml-version-1-0-using-xdocument/)

Comment: I found where is the problem .. it is on encoding C# use UTF-8 as defaults. text are UTF-16 and my xml file is UTF-16 too. thank you for your help and look to my new ansower